# How is $maxDistance measured in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I can't seem to find this information.  But using a geo search you can specify `$maxDistance` but for the life of me, I can't find if that is miles, kilometers, etc.

Here is a sample query I'm using:

```
db.hotels.find( { location: { $near : [18.74255, 99.03523], $maxDistance : 0.05 } } ).count()
```

Returns 15 (from my hotels database).

Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unless you're doing a spherical query (like `$nearSphere`), MongoDB doesn't actually care about units, it just treats your locations as Cartesian coordinates.

So, the calculated distance is going to be in whatever your input units were. Since your `$near` point looks like standard lat/long, the `$maxDistance` in this case will be in units of degrees.

Comment: What is units of degrees? I am doing the almost exact query as cbmeeks. What maxdistance should I set if I need results from within 1 km?

Comment: It's not exact, but for a rough conversion, you can divide your desired distance in kilometers by 111. (For miles, you would divide by about 69.)

Comment: Just to be more exact since I just researched for this and this can clearly help future visitors, the actual formula is : 1° latitude = 69.047 miles = 111.12 kilometers

Comment: It is not so simple for longitude though, since the conversion factor changes with latitude.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `$near`,

```
$maxDistance = your distance in Kms / 111
```

and if you use `$nearSphere`,

```
$maxDistance = your distance in kms/ 6378
```

where `6378` is the earths radius in kms