# Mongodb Exception "point not in interval of [ -180, 180 ]

Tags: mongodb, exception, location

I have a collection 'place' ,one documentis as below

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("52401a7267778834a23a54a2"),
"userid" : "123",
"loc" : {
    "lng" : 77.6166685, 
    "lat" : 12.9361732 
},
"t" : ISODate("2013-04-23T10:39:46.540Z")
```

}

I want to find out locations of user with userid 234 and loc near to [77.6166685,12.9361732] within 1km

but the below query is not working

```
db.place.find({{"userid":"234","loc":{"$near":{"$geometry":{"type":"point","coordinates":[77.6166685,12.9361732]},"$maxDistance":1000}}})
```

it showing error as given below

```
error: {
    "$err" : "point not in interval of [ -180, 180 ] :: caused by :: { 0: 0.0, 1: 250.0 }",
    "code" : 16433
```

}

what is this error and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem is the following:

You document has a form which is applicable for "2d" indexes, (you have not told what kind of indexes do you have) and you are trying to query it with a [query which](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-a-2dsphere-index/#proximity-to-a-geojson-point) is applicable for "2dsphere" indexes. So you have two options:

- convert the document to GeoJSON format (here you are not specifying geometry), put 2dsphere index and to query it in this way
- do nothing and to query it [with a correct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/maxDistance/#op._S_maxDistance) way with "2d" indexes

I have done in the second way:

```
db.d.find({
  "loc":{
      "$near": [77.6166685,12.9361732],
      "$maxDistance":1000
  }
})
```

and got a correct result.

Comment: this query returns me  result,but I think  "$maxDistance":1000 is not working as we expected.it returning result greater distance  than 1KM.the doc of $maxDistance only specifies distance in unit not in meter

Comment: Can you show me the that wrong result (with a distance bigger then 1km). Based on documentation it is in meters.

Comment: db.place.find({loc:{$near:[77.6166685,12.9361732],$maxDistance:1000}}).skip(525).limit(1) 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("529a9ccf67778812342a"), "userid" : "234", "loc" : { "lng" : 76.2014665, "lat" : 10.5349755 }, "t" : ISODate("2013-11-01T02:19:59.518Z") }

Comment: actually this is strange. Right now no idea why does this happen.

Comment: may be this is the answer for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319988/how-is-maxdistance-measured-in-mongodb

Comment: @sajith Exactly, you are right. Here you are not using spherical query and therefore that answer is applicable.

Comment: so instead of  "$maxDistance":1000 i will use  "$maxDistance":0.009 (1/111.12, because approximatly 111.12KM=1 radian)